# Simplifying nested Maybe pattern matching

Tags: haskell, nested, pattern-matching, simplify, option-type

I have the following construct in my code:

```
f :: Maybe A -> X
f a = case a of
  Nothing -> x
  (Just b) -> case b of
    Nothing -> y
    (Just c) -> case c of
      Nothing -> z
      (Just d) -> d
```

I'm not seeing an obvious way to simplify this instead of using nested `maybe` functions, which wouldn't make the whole thing look much better. Are there any clever - but still understandable - tricks that would help make this construct more "elegant"?

Comment: You need a better structure for the problem then nested `Maybe`

Comment: It seems a little odd that you don't care about the values of b and c, just whether or not they have values.  This makes them effectively Boolean.  Is the layer of Maybes arbitrarily deep or a fixed depth?

Comment: Your model is basically wrong.  You need to be chaining (i.e. mapping over) functions/functors, not doing this imperative style.

Comment: @itsbruce: What does that mean, in plain English? (Aka, what’s the translation function?)

Comment: **The answers here are useless**, because they arrogantly imply, that you have merely a nested Maybe, and the given example is not just a simplified idea of a much more complex (set of) function(s) that returns Maybe values too, as is commeon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED 2**

`Monad Either` is for you

```
import Data.Maybe (maybe)

maybeE :: e -> Maybe a -> Either e a
maybeE e = maybe (Left e) Right

f :: Maybe (Maybe (Maybe d)) -> Either e d
f a  =   maybeE x a 
     >>= maybeE y
     >>= maybeE z
```

**UPDATED 3**

If we want to have not `Either` type, we could rewrite function:

```
import Data.Either(either)

either' = either id id

f :: Maybe (Maybe (Maybe d)) -> d
f a = either' $ maybeE x a 
            >>= maybeE y
            >>= maybeE z
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the `Maybe` monad would help here, `a` has a type of `Maybe (Maybe (Maybe ...)))`, and after every `Maybe` layer I have to return a different value if it evaluates to `Nothing`, (`x y z` in the above example).

Comment: This could be re-written so that f takes an arbitrary-size list of Eitherss as the single parameter.  Would be better, I think.  But that's a comment aimed at the OP, not you, viorior.

Comment: @itsbruce what would the type of `f` be if you allowed it to take an arbitrary-size list of `Either`s?  Oh, you mean instead of the nested `Maybes`.

Comment: Precisely! :)  It should be `f :: [something] -> d` where `something` can probably just be functors to be mapped over, frankly.  This kind of thing doesn't need more complexity than that.

Comment: I ended up using your `maybeE` combinator for my needs, but the other answers are very informative too!

Comment: @PhilipK Just out of curiosity, what makes `maybeE x a >>= maybeE y >>= maybeE z` preferable over `maybe x . maybe y . maybe z $ id` to you? (I'm trying to improve some newbie Haskell material, so I appreciate every indication I can get about how people think.)

Comment: @kqr: as it turns out, I simplified the actual code way too much, if I had to use `maybe` it would look something like `maybe x (\a -> maybe y (maybe ...) (doSomethingWith a))`. In comparison, a monadic do block looks quite nice.

Answer (score 13):

Why did the code construct a `Maybe (Maybe (Maybe X))` value in the first place? Unpacking such a value isn't nice, but the real question is, why there even is such a value. Maybe the code would better avoid all those nested Maybes.

If you really need to have such a value and need to do different things in all the `Just`/`Nothing` cases you'll have to write them all down. But instead of several nested `case` statements you could combine them into one big pattern match:

```
f Nothing                = x
f (Just Nothing))        = y
f (Just (Just Nothing))  = z 
f (Just (Just (Just d))) = d
```

Comment: I'm parsing a nested JSON value with a lot of "nullable" types, so that's why there are so many arbitrarily nested `Maybes`.

Answer (score 8):

Despite your constraint about not using `maybe`, I think this looks quite nice:

```
f = maybe x (maybe y (maybe z id))
```

or even better, as @pat suggests in his comment:

```
f = maybe x . maybe y . maybe z $ id
```

Comment: Or `f = maybe x . maybe y . maybe z $ id`