# Updating a nested Maybe

Tags: elm

elm n00b. I've read that Elm requires `Maybe`s be handled explicitly. That said when dealing with nested `Maybe`s, is there a way/pattern of expressing things to say "if all the `Maybe`s contain values then do something, else give me this default"?

I'd think `Maybe.andThen` except I don't see how it would fit here.

The closest I've come to a similar question is in Haskell: [Simplifying nested Maybe pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655870/simplifying-nested-maybe-pattern-matching)

Sample code that can be run at try-elm follows. We model a "box", that may contain a playing "marble", that may have a number of "vanes" (or flutes) at its center. `updateBox` increments the number of vanes, if any (assume it updates other values not shown here, hence the name)

What I'm looking for is a succinct way to say: "if the marble exists, and if it has vanes, give me a new marble w/ incremented vanes; else give me back marble as-is".

(Please note this could be restructured to avoid the nested Maybe traversal, but that's not the question.)

Aside: IMO it feels odd to need to say `Nothing -> Just marble` below at the `-- why do we need Just?` comment. The code is already following the `Just marble` path, so shouldn't it follow that the marble at that point is already a `Just marble`?

```
import Html exposing (text)

main =
  text (toString (updateBox mybox))

type alias Box = 
  {marble: Maybe Marble}

type alias Marble = 
  {vanes: Maybe Int}

mybox = Box <| Just <| Marble <| Just 1

updateBox: Box -> Box
updateBox b =
  let
    updateMarble marble =
      case marble of
        Just marble ->
          case marble.vanes of
            Just vanes -> Just {marble | vanes = Just(vanes + 1)}
            Nothing -> Just marble -- why do we need Just?
        Nothing -> marble
  in
    {b | marble = updateMarble b.marble}
```

Comment: Fyi you don't need to pass through arguments to a function in a let block, you can access them directly if you want. `updateBox b =   let     updateMarble = case b.marble of `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Maybe.map`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Maybe#map) to eliminate the need for explicit `Nothing` checks:

```
updateBox: Box -> Box
updateBox b =
    {b | marble = Maybe.map (\m -> { m | vanes = Maybe.map ((+) 1) m.vanes }) b.marble}
```